# How to set filtering by the combination of letters?

Tags: javascript, webix

I'm using Webix and I need to customize suggest in the сombo box.
As I can see, basically suggest filter provides to search by the first letters, but I need more flexible search function in my app. 
Is it possible to set filtering by the combination of letters located anywhere in the word or phrase?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151108/custom-filter-for-combo, it shows how the combo filter can be redefined

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps webix functionality is not possible, what I did was do the search using like SQL.

[Window, text, combo, button and list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nizQ.jpg)